# Service running in Fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, service, multidimensional-array, android-fragments

I have three tabs and three fragments each.I have a Service running in one of the fragment , Service is receiving the messages from the network and updating the fragment because broadcast receiver for that Service is in the fragment.I want to keep the Service running and updating the fragment all the time even that particular tab is selected or not.When I change the tab without stoping the Service, my app get crash.
Also in main activity on `ActionBar.TabListener` I have `

```
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                 ft.remove(fragment);
                //ft.hide(fragment);
            }
```

`
Please help me how achieve this thing ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you change the tab, that `Fragment` will be destroyed, and the view for that fragment will get destroyed as well. You will no longer be able to update that `Fragment`.

You should approach different this problem :

1. Somehow cache whatever the `Service` is retrieving, and once the `Fragment` is created get latest data from cache and displayed
2. (Similar) use a bound `Service` that continuously retrieves your "data" and stores it inside the `Service`, once your `Fragment` gets created, bind to the `Service` and retrieve that data.

Comment: thanks ,you told the right idea but what if I use the startService() and stopService() in order to start and stop the service rather than binding it?

Comment: that would be ok too.. I just thought that you need to constantly retrieve the data in the service.

Comment: so that would be ok too? I will get what I want ? No difference between startservice and bindservice?